# Instantiate Handsontable with no data

Tags: handsontable

Seems like a simple task yet I haven't found a simple solution yet. My data sometimes comes as an empty array so that the user can start working off of an empty table (except for the headers). The table has a `minSpareRows:1` so I was hoping the table would appear with that spare row and nothing else but instead it goes entirely blank.

Any ideas on how to instantiate a table with just the spare row and the column headers?

Things I've tried include manually inserting a row if the data array is empty however this leads to there being an empty row plus a spare row.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `minRows` and `minCols` to instantiate an empty Handsontable instance. Also, the `data` arguments expects an array of arrays, so in your case when you receive an empty array, just wrap it in another one:

```
data : Array of Arrays (default [ [] ])
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/9bx3ke4g/)'s a working JSFiddle.